# Array Compare and get count

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I  am new in this. I have Multiple array list:

```
    var fruits1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
    var fruits2 = ["O", "E", "F", "G"];
    var fruits3 = ["S", "D", "E", "S"];
    var fruits4 = ["A", "B", "Z", "A"];
    var fruits5 = ["A", "R", "U", "V"];
    var fruits6 = ["N", "B", "O", "M"];
    var fruits7 = ["A", "B", "N", "P"];
    var fruits8 = ["X", "C", "Z", "Z"];
    var fruits9 = ["X", "B", "X", "B"];
```

The array having number of times like following things.

```
    A - 5
    B - 6
    C - 2
    D - 2
    E - 2
    F - 1
    G - 1
    M - 1
    N - 2
    O - 2
    P - 1
    R - 1
    S - 2
    U - 1
    V - 1
    X - 3
    Z - 3
```

Need  output like this using javascript/jquery

```
[{"B" : 6}, { "A" : 5}, {"X":3}, {"Z" : 3}, {"C" : 2}, { "D" : 2}, { "E" : 2}, { "N" : 2}, { "O" :2}, { "S" : 2}, { "F": 1 }, { "G" :1}, { "M" :1}, { "P" :1}, { "R" :1}, { "U" :1}, { "V" :1 }]
```

Can anyone have idea to do this?

Comment: There are few possibles to come the values. 1. array value come repeated with the same array. 2. array value repeated to other array.

Comment: Do you want to get the index of an alphabet or the count of number of times it appeared in the array?

Comment: `fruits1`, `fruits2`, `fruits3`? You should probably build a `fruits` array, first.

Comment: Count the number of  repeated values, and display the object order wise. (which one have top most in first place like this)

Comment: @RSKMR: Why do you need a output format like that? Does it need to be _exactly_ like that, or can the format be changed slightly, to make accessing it easier?

Comment: @Cerbrus - Actually i have 10 line text. Each line get from different website. I need to show what are the text repeated with count wise. So i do first step i split the line(10 lines). I get 10 arrays. If you have any other idea?

Comment: Why an array of objects as the output? Seems like that is one extra level of data structure that you don't, why not a simple object?

Comment: @Mike - Please suggest which one is best one. But i expect the output is to display the character with count(desc order).

Comment: @RSKMR Ah. You didn't mention sort in your original question. that actually does make a difference in terms of data structure, such that an array (which can imply order) is required.

Comment: I showed the example with order wise. sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be overthinking this, but here's what I've come up with:

```js
var fruits1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    fruits2 = ["O", "E", "F", "G"],
    fruits3 = ["S", "D", "E", "S"],
    fruits4 = ["A", "B", "Z", "A"],
    fruits5 = ["A", "R", "U", "V"],
    fruits6 = ["N", "B", "O", "M"],
    fruits7 = ["A", "B", "N", "P"],
    fruits8 = ["X", "C", "Z", "Z"],
    fruits9 = ["X", "B", "X", "B"],
    fruits= [].concat(fruits1, fruits2, fruits3, fruits4, fruits5, fruits6, fruits7, fruits8, fruits9),
    cnt= {},
    output= [];

fruits.forEach(function(val) {
  cnt[val]= (cnt[val] || 0)+1
});

Object.keys(cnt).forEach(function(val, idx) {
  var obj= {};
  obj[val]= cnt[val];
  output.push(obj);
});

output= output.sort(function(a, b) {
  var ak= Object.keys(a)[0],
      bk= Object.keys(b)[0],
      a1= a[ak],
      b1= b[bk];
  return a1 < b1 ? 1 : a1 > b1 ? -1 : 
         ak < bk ? -1 : ak > bk ? 1 : 0;
});

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML= JSON.stringify(output);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

The `concat` function joins all the arrays into a single array named `fruit`.

The `fruits.forEach` loop stores the total fruits in a `cnt` object, which looks like this:  `{"A": 5, "B": 6, "C": 2, ...}`.

The `Object.keys(cnt).forEach` loop pushes the `cnt` keys into an `output` array.

The `output.sort` function then sorts the values, first by descending number of items, then by ascending key.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to have only array of all the fruits, Then use the following mapping-

i.e. in your case I merged the array into single one-

```
var fruits = ["A", "B", "C", "D","O", "E", "F", "G","S", "D", "E", "S","A", "B", "Z", "A","A", "R", "U", "V","N", "B", "O", "M","A", "B", "N", "P","X", "C", "Z", "Z","X", "B", "X", "B"];
```

**and then-**

```
var counts = {};

for(var i = 0; i< fruits.length; i++) {
    var fruit = fruits[i];
    counts[fruit] = counts[fruit] ? counts[fruit]+1 : 1;

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pjebu77j/1/)

Comment: Nice. Its possible to show order wise? i need to display in order wise (which one have most count) .